# Unable to connect to Github for the first time

Tags: linux, terminal, git, opensuse, github

This is my first time with Git and I'm trying to set it up on my box. I added my key to my profile in the Github web interface. When I try to connect... :

```
max@linux-vwzy:~> ssh git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

max@linux-vwzy:~> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /home/max/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/max/.ssh/id_rsa)

max@linux-vwzy:~> ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

I'm supposed to be getting some kind of welcome message however, I'm not.

Comment: It might be a problem on their end - a PTY allocation failure is a pretty low level error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `ssh git@github.com` in a normal terminal environment, your SSH client (the *ssh* process on your local machine) will request a psuedo-terminal (pty) from the server.

GitHub has always denied pty allocation.

Older versions (prior to 5.6) of OpenSSH’s *ssh* will “fall back” to no-pty mode if the server rejected its pty allocation request.

Newer versions (5.6 through 5.8) of OpenSSH’s *ssh* abort if the server rejects its pty allocation request.

The latest versions (5.9 and later) of OpenSSH’s *ssh* will take the former action (continue) if the pty allocation was done automatically, and the latter action (abort) if there was an explicit request for a pty (`-t` given or `RequestTTY` equal to `yes`/`force`).

You can tell *ssh* (either old or new) to avoid requesting a pty allocation by using the `-T` option:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

You should then see the GitHub message:

> Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

---

From the [OpenSSH 5.6 release announcement](http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=128256356229601):

> - Kill channel when pty allocation requests fail. Fixed stuck client
>     if the server refuses pty allocation (bz#1698)

`bz#1698` seems to be a reference to a [report logged in the “Portable OpenSSH” Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1698).

---

From the check-in message of [OpenSSH clientloop.c rev 1.234](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/clientloop.c#rev1.234):

> improve our behaviour when TTY allocation fails: if we are in
>   RequestTTY=auto mode (the default), then do not treat at TTY
>   allocation error as fatal but rather just restore the local TTY
>   to cooked mode and continue. This is more graceful on devices that
>   never allocate TTYs.
>
> If RequestTTY is set to "yes" or "force", then failure to allocate
>   a TTY is fatal.